# Index out of range in math function

Tags: python

Below is my version of something someone I know was working on for school in Java. I wanted to challenge myself with it by choosing a pretty convoluted method and making use of only loops, if statements, and other such elementary Python stuff that's learned before things like objects, classes, recursion.

I need to take a number greater than 1 as input, which I limited in this case to a max of 30 just until I get my function working. The function needs to output a number that is the result of finding two numbers that multiply together to produce the original input number (example, 3 and 7 for input 21), whose concatenated digits also give the input number as their product, by making sure that if you multiply each number by the next from left to right successively, you will also produce the original input number.

Among all possible outputs this function could give, the function finally chooses the lowest number and gives it as the output. So even if 144 *were* going to give a successful output number, it wouldn't use the 12, 12 pair because the output would be 1212 and there's definitely another pair (such as 2, 72) that gives a smaller final output.

*Examples*:

```
>>> thing(21)
37

>>> thing(144)
```

Probably nothing works, right? So this would return `None` or `False` or give the user a failure message.

If it weren't for the rule of the digits of the number resulting from concatenating the pair of numbers having to also produce the input number, the input 144 would return/print 1212. However, because of the rule, 1 x 2 x 1 x 2 = 4 and not 144, therefore it doesn't work.

I'm getting an error about a string index being out of range.

```
def thing(n):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    calc = False
    count = 0
    if n > 1 and n < 30:
        for x in range(1, n + 1):
            for y in range(1, n + 1):
                if (x * y) == n:
                    list1.append([x, y])
                    for pair in list1:
                        digits = str(pair[0]) + str(pair[1])
                        holder = int(digits[count])
                        while count < (len(digits) - 1):
                            holder *= int(digits[count+1])
                            count += 1
                            if count == len(digits)-1:
                                if holder == n:
                                    list2.append(holder)
                                    calc = True
                                    count = 0
                                else:
                                    count = 0
    else:
        print("Input invalid.")
    if calc:
        print(min(list2))
    else:
        print("No such number.")
```

I am doing this inefficient and convoluted method **on purpose** and consider it training.

BUT, I will still gladly take suggestions not only for improving this code in its own method, but *also* suggestions for writing this with far fewer lines in a more high-level way.

It's possible that even using low-level Python knowledge to solve this, there's a much shorter way to do it that I've missed. I know that even in my method, I can probably get it a few lines shorter, maybe one less variable, stuff like that, but so far I've only been trying to make it work first.

Note: I don't come from a math background. (Can I succeed in the industry without any advanced math?)

Comment: try codereveiw.stackexchange.org

Comment: There are a lot of questions in here, but it seems like the main one is "why does this throw an index out of range error", which is ok for SO.

Comment: It's a little bit hard not to read this as: *"I'm doing this wrong on purpose - why is it wrong?"*

Comment: In which line is the Index Out Of Range?

Comment: Do you mean to nest the `for` loops? It seems silly to add a pair to `list1`, and then immediately process it and every pair before it again.

Comment: Also, that final `while` loop will run forever. You're resetting `count` to `0` every time it hits the loop's exit condition.

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley will do! I assume then that that is the proper place for questions for which I include all my code.

Comment: @MattCoubrough it's not a matter of refusing to do it the right way, but of choosing this way as a difficult or time consuming programming exercise. I stated in my post that I am interested both in advice for my way, and in how to do it in much better ways.

Comment: @Jasper sorry for not including that.

Comment: @killermonkey50 I'm not really sure what you mean? About the loop: Yeah, I thought that too but then I couldn't figure out why it was still doing that. That's just my inexperience I guess. I fixed it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening in the case where `count != len(digits)-1` as `count` is not reset to zero, causing an index error in the next iteration. I think you're looking for something like:

```
                    if count == len(digits)-1:
                        if holder == n:
                            list2.append(holder)
                            calc = True
                            count = 0
                        else:
                            count = 0
                    else:
                        count = 0
```

Additionally, it appears the `while` loop at the end of your code will run forever, since you're setting count to zero before the `while` checks its condition. In that case:

```
                while count < (len(digits) - 1):
                    holder *= int(digits[count+1])
                    count += 1
                    if count == len(digits)-1:
                        if holder == n:
                            list2.append(holder)
                            calc = True
                count = 0
```

Would be your solution.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. I had also been doing a few other things wrong, but changing these was the first step!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Thanks for the help, guys!

Let me also restate that I was looking for both help towards solving it my way, AND towards solving it in much better ways. Thus, all help is gladly accepted :)
I'm still interested in the much better ways!

I had also forgotten some things like switching holder's value back to int(digits) so that I'm returning the concatenated number pair rather than stupidly returning the input itself after achieving it.

Here's my working answer, at long last! (I wanted to get the satisfaction of completing the function in the dumb, time-consuming way I'd chosen to do it :D)

```
def thing(n):

    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    calc = False
    count = 0

    if n > 1 and n < 30:
        for x in range(1, n + 1):
            for y in range(1, n + 1):
                if (x * y) == n:
                    list1.append([x, y])
    else:
        print("Input invalid.")
        return

    for pair in list1:
        digits = str(pair[0]) + str(pair[1])
        holder = int(digits[count])
        while count < (len(digits) - 1):
            holder *= int(digits[count + 1])
            count += 1
        if holder == n:
            holder = int(digits)
            list2.append(holder)
            calc = True
        count = 0
    if calc:
        print(min(list2))
    else:
        print("No such number.")
```